# How can I print the base two representation of a number without using any array in C?

Tags: c

I need to print my characters BEFORE the previously printed character using `printf`. For example:

```
printf("1")
printf("0")
```

would need to output:

```
01
```

Is there a way to do this? I cannot use arrays. To be clear I'm printing in base two (binary) representation using a divide by two algorithm:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){ // 16 bit int
    tmp = num % 2;
    if(tmp == 1){
      printf("1");
    } else {
      printf("0");
    }
    num /= 2;
  }
```

The above code prints the binary representation backwards.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Why can't you just swap the two `printf` statements? I'm sure there is a reason but your description does not explain that clearly.

Comment: You can't alter the output once it's been output, so either reverse the order or think of a different approach, perhaps buffering, then altering before output.

Comment: Depending on your terminal and use case, you could maybe do something with escape sequences https://shiroyasha.svbtle.com/escape-sequences-a-quick-guide-1 i.e. After printing 1, you could move the cursor to the start of the line and print 01 overtop of it (assuming you "remember" that you printed one the first time). But it would help to understand the real use case.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299022). Could you state a) why and b) in what environment you want to achieve this (e.g. does it have to work if piped to a file)?

Comment: Perhaps whoever gave you the assignment is hoping you will solve it recursively.

Comment: IMHO the instructor is trying to be too clever for their own good, to the extent that one could claim incompetency in teaching, for there's no need for obfuscation. In any case: recursion is not some free lunch. When you recurse, you implicitly create a periodic (array!) data structure on the stack, on-the-fly. So I call bullshit. Sure, the code doesn't show any explicit array, but it definitely needs state, and the state - due to repeating nature of recursion - is represented in a periodic fashion, *exactly* as an array would be, as long as you only have a single callpoint for recursing.

Comment: This is true enough that you can overlay the stack with a suitably designed `struct` in an array, and retrieve all the state thus saved. By pretending that this somehow doesn't happen, the instructor is obfuscating simple implementation details that actually make the whole thing work. Yes, compilers are free to do all sorts of things to your code that make it not necessarily a practical nor portable approach, but just because you may have a hard time predicting the ad-hoc array's layout a priori doesn't change the principle of it. Recursion is just an implicit form of array-laying.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to print binary without using array. you can ignore initial zeros by adding another if condition.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num =50;
    int i;

    for(i=15;i>=0;i--){
        if( (1<<i) & num){
            printf("1");
        }
        else printf("0");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0000000000110010
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion can perform like a "print before".  [@rici](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63947401/how-can-i-print-a-character-before-the-previously-printed-character-c/63948448#comment113080472_63947401)

The below does not always print 16 digits, just the decimal digits needed.

```
void print_binary(unsigned n) {
  // Break the digits into 2 groups: 1) the one least digit and 2) the rest.
  unsigned last_digit = n/10;
  unsigned all_the_other_more_significant_digits = n/10;

  // Let us print those more significant digits first;
  if (all_the_other_more_significant_digits > 0) {
    print_binary(all_the_other_more_significant_digits);
  }

  // Now print the last digit
  printf("%u", last_digit);
}
```